# Group Policy restricting Administrators

Tags: windows, group-policy

I want to disable users being able to use CMD. This is what I did with my Administrator account: [image]

However, for some reason my Administrator account also got restricted from command prompt:
[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need filter the GPO to do not apply to Administrators group.